# Why does LWP::UserAgent GET request fail with HTTPS?

Tags: perl

Here's my code

```
#!/path/to/perl
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use Crypt::SSLeay;

$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = 'http://proxy:8080/';

$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;


my $myurl = "https://www.redhat.com";

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->cookie_jar( {} ); 
$ua->protocols_allowed( [ 'http','https'] );
$ua->proxy(['http', 'https'], 'http://proxy:8080/');

my $page = $ua->get($myurl);

die "Error $myurl\n ", $page->status_line, "\n Aborting" 
unless $page->is_success; 
print "Success", $page1->content_type, " document!\n";
```

It returns

```
Error at https://www.redhat.com
400 Bad Request
Aborting at test.pl line 30.
```

what's wrong?

Edit:

Apparently, Its a [bug](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=1894). But the workaround doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ha! I got the answer!

1) remove the '/' after the port of ENV{HTTPS_PROXY}

2) Apparently, LWP's proxy system send 'GET' requests instead of CONNECT requests so use Crypt::SSLeay's proxy system by just setting the environment variable and remove the proxy command.

Answer (score 1):

On some systems, e.g. Debian, you need to install the appropriate SSL library for this to work. The error messages on theses systems can sometimes be at bit missleading. I think the Debian package would be libnet-ssleay-perl.

Answer (score 1):

I just uploaded the LWP::Protocol::connect module to CPAN. This module adds the missing HTTP/CONNECT method support to LWP.

```
 use LWP::UserAgent;

 $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(); 
 $ua->proxy('https', 'connect://proxyhost.domain:3128/');

 $ua->get('https://www.somesslsite.com');
```

With this module you can use the regular IO::Socket::SSL implementation for LWP >=6.00.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your proxy server does not accept HTTPS connections. Have you tried setting it up in your favorite browser and viewing the URL?

Comment: I have. It works. The proxy is not a problem. There's a bug I've linked in my original post. Some problem about sending a GET to a proxy. But the workaround suggested doesnt work for me