# Perl HTTPS over proxy using LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl, https, proxy, lwp, lwp-useragent

I wish to request a URL via a HTTPS proxy using perl's LWP::UserAgent module. There is quite a few reference around this, but nothing could help me get it work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;

BEGIN {
    $ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = 'https://<IP>:<PORT>';
    $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;
    $ENV{HTTPS_PROXY_USERNAME} = '<API_KEY>';
    $ENV{HTTPS_PROXY_PASSWORD} = '';
    $ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;  #Add debug output
}

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => {verify_hostname => 0}, SSL_version => 'SSLv3', allowed_protocols => ['https', 'http']);
$ua->proxy(['https', 'http'], 'https://<IP>:<PORT>');
my $req = HTTP::Request->new('GET','https://<DOMAIN_URL>');
print STDERR Dumper($ua);
my $response = $ua->request($req);
print $response->code ."\n";
print STDERR Dumper($response);
```

I get this error:

> SSL connect attempt failed error:140770FC:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol at
>   /home/user/project/local/lib/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.

Despite me specifying allowed_protocols in LWP, https scheme in proxy and the url scheme being https, it still goes to LWP::Protocol::HTTP above and not to LWP::Protocol::HTTPS.

I also verified that the version of LWP::Protocol::HTTPS is 6.06 which is the same as LWP::UserAgent (which was mentioned in one of the forums)

Comment: Fixed! Any suggestions for me to try out

Comment: Not really I'm afraid. If you can provide a server to test with, I can play around. But off the top of my head I have no ideas.

Comment: Its a private proxy cloud with credentials..

Comment: Why are you setting `SSLv3`? Is that because you really need it, or because you saw it somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(); 
$ua->proxy('https', 'connect://<USER>:<PSWD>@<IP>:<PORT>/');

$ua->get('https://www.somesslsite.com');
```

[HTTPS Proxy and LWP::UserAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116244/https-proxy-and-lwpuseragent?rq=1)

Note: The environment credentials (HTTPS_PROXY_USERNAME) didnt work for me. I had to enter it in the URL like above.

Comment: The `connect://` scheme works only if you have `LWP::Protocol::connect` installed. It works also with version of LWP before 6.06. But with versions starting with 6.06 I recommend to use the builtin proxy facility because you  don't have to install an additional modul.

Answer (score 2):

The correct setup with recent versions of LWP (starting with version 6.06 which you have) is to just use the same syntax as found in other applications together with the `proxy` function:

```
 my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
 $ua->proxy(https => 'http://user:pass@proxy');
 $ua->get('https://server');
```

Alternatively you could set the environment variable `https_proxy` to the same value, i.e. `http://user:pass@proxy`.

Before 6.06 proxy support was broken at least when used together with IO::Socket::SSL (default since version 6.0). The syntax you have in your question is for the old backend `Crypt::SSLeay` which is no longer recommended because it does not check the certificates properly.

Comment: Agreed. OP, please see [Do you need Crypt::SSLeay?](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::SSLeay#DO-YOU-NEED-Crypt::SSLeay) and [Does your code really depend on Crypt::SSLeay?](https://www.nu42.com/2014/04/does-your-code-really-depend-on.html).